# Beetles on my fruit trees

Tags: fruit-trees, insects, pest-damage

I have some plum and peach trees and have noticed several of these beetles on each one. There are also a lot of holes in the leaves which I assume are the beetles eating them. Now if that’s just cosmetic I don’t mind, but if not, should I get rid of them and how? Located in Illinois [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are [Japanese Beetles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_beetle) or Popillia japonica.  In my yard they eat roses  and last year was really bad.

Control is all a matter of timing. As wikipedia suggests

> when present in small numbers, the beetles may be manually controlled
> using a soap-water spray mixture, shaking a plant in the morning hours
> and disposing of the fallen beetles,[13] or simply picking them off
> attractions such as rose flowers, since the presence of beetles
> attracts more beetles to that plant

Pheromone traps seem to attract more beetles than caught in the trap.  A bucket of soap and water seems easier