# Should I prune skeletonized leaves?

Tags: fruit-trees, pest-damage

Follow up to [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/39492/21512).

I've killed all of the Japanese beetles on my fruit trees, and will continue to monitor them every morning.

Unfortunately I have a lot of skeletonized leaves. Seems like they mostly went after the newest leaves.

Should I prune these leaves off? Normally when I prune dead leaves they come off easily as if the tree itself wants to get rid of them. These leaves do not come off easily so I'm worried about damaging the tree if it "wants" to keep them.